# Is there a way to test the size (height and width) of the view using espresso for android Instrumentation test?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso

> I want to check if the visibility and size of the `adFrame` changes after clicking the `buttonShow`

```
onView(withId(buttonShow)).perform(click());
onView(withId(adFrame)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
onView(withId(adFrame)).check(?);
```

I am looking for a solution of **this ?**.

> Do we have an assertion that can test the size of the `adFrame` using the espresso for this **Android Instrumentation test**?

Answer (score 0):

Given the following matchers:

```
class WidthMatcher(private val width: Int = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
    companion object {
        fun withWidth(width: Int) = WidthMatcher(width)
    }

    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("View with width: ${width}px")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: View): Boolean {
        return item.layoutParams?.width == width
    }
}

class HeightMatcher(private val height: Int = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT) : TypeSafeMatcher<View>() {
    companion object {
        fun withHeight(height: Int) = HeightMatcher(height)
    }

    override fun describeTo(description: Description?) {
        description?.appendText("View with height: ${height}px")
    }

    override fun matchesSafely(item: View): Boolean {
        return item.layoutParams?.height == height
    }
}
```

You just have to check as follows:

```
onView(withId(adFrame)).check(matches(withHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT)))
```

You can also check for any size in px. You can convert from dp to px by using:

```
/**
 * Converts dp unit to its equivalent in pixels, based on device density.
 *
 * @param dp The value in dp (density independent pixels) unit aim to convert into pixels
 * @return The equivalent int value in px of the provided dp value depending on device density
 */
fun dpToPx(dp: Int): Int {
    (dp * Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).roundToInt()
}

/**
 * This method converts device specific pixels to density independent pixels.
 *
 * @param px A value in px (pixels) unit. Which we need to convert into db
 * @return The equivalent int value in dp of the provided px value depending on device density
 */
fun pxToDp(px: Int): Int {
    (px / Resources.getSystem().displayMetrics.density).roundToInt()
}
```